# Poisson regression by group

Tags: python, regression, grouping, statsmodels, poisson

I have sales data that show daily sales per product per region and some predictor variables, im trying to run a poisson regression (as count data). Doing a pearson correlation on the whole dataset without taking into account region is pretty weak but when taking into account region shows better results.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['29/10/20', 'apple', 'east', 2, 50], 
    ['29/10/20', 'apple', 'west', 1, 300], 
    ['29/10/20', 'orange', 'east', 3, 300],
    ['30/10/20', 'apple', 'east', 3, 200],
    ['30/10/20', 'orange', 'east', 1, 30], 
    ['30/10/20', 'orange', 'west', 2, 10]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'product', 'region', 'sales', 'predictor1'])
```

i know i can use groupby to split the correlation by region

```
df.groupby(["region"]).corr()
```

I'd like to do a similar thing for the Poisson regression. Am i right in thinking the 'groups' arguement does this? or have I misunderstood

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm
    
glm(formula="sales ~ predictor1 ", groups=df['region'], data=df, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

Comment: glm doesn't have a groups keyword. I gues you want `formula="sales ~ predictor1 + region "` or  `formula="sales ~ predictor1 : region "`

Comment: would this still be the case for multiple predictor variables? would you report a separate equation for each region. Sorry if this isnt making sense, new to stats and python

Comment: All variables that are interacted with the region categories will have coefficients for each region, e.g. "(a + b + c) : region". See docs for ":" in https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html

Comment: If you want completely separate regression, then search for answer for pandas groupby used with OLS, that will apply also to GLM.

Comment: Thankd Josef what is the difference between the 2 methods you say or are they essentially the same thing? I know there are differences per region in all the predictor variables just trying to work out what would be best

Comment: In the Poisson case there is not much difference, in OLS the residual variance would be estimated either over the full model or for each subset separately which only affects standard errors and not parameter estimates. The advantage of combining into one model is that hypothesis test can be made across region parameters.

Comment: memory requirement of the full model will be much larger if there are many regions

Comment: thats great, thanks for your help really cleared things up for me